# Angular JS Animation not calling beforeAddClass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-animation

I am trying to create an animation using AngJS 1.2.15

I have defined a directive who's purpose is to create a post element and pass showAnswer boolean to the element.

And created a animation module which it animates on if a answer class is added/removed to the post element.

The HTML binds the two together by assigning/removing answer as a class if the showAnswer is true/false dependent on mouseenter/mouseleave.

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>

  <post class="boxWrapper answer-animation"
    ng-class="{'answer':showAnswer}"
    ng-repeat='q in questions'
    ng-mouseenter='showAnswer = true'
    ng-mouseleave='showAnswer = false'>


    <div class = 'box'>
      <div class="front jumbotron"><h1>{{q.question}}</h1></div>
      <div class="back jumbotron"><h1>{{q.answer}}</h1></div>
    </div>

  </post>
</div>
```

THE MODULES

```
app.directive('post', function() {


var controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.showAnswer = false;
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    controller: controller
  }
});

app.animation('.answer-animation', function(){
  return {
    beforeAddClass: function(element, className, done){
      if (className == 'answer') {

        console.log('I am Called - ADD');

        }
      else {
        done();
      }
    },

    beforeRemoveClass: function(element, className, done) {
      if (className == 'answer') {

        console.log('I am Called - REMOVE');

        }
      else {
        done();
      }
    }
  };

});
```

Now I have put in console.logs to show what I expect to happen, but these logs are never called which implies the beforeAddClass & beforeRemoveClass are never called, even though I can clearly see the answer class being added to the  element! :( Stuck!

Comment: Simple thing first, are you injecting `ngAnimate` to your module? Also creating a fiddle or plnkr would be helpful in determining the issue.

Comment: Works (as long as you have added ngAnimate as a dependency): http://plnkr.co/edit/rx74sXmucFV2k30Ssnzm?p=preview

Comment: Dude you the man! I was using injecting $animate, I think the blog I was reading was an older version of Anjs! Thanks!!